# HTTP error code for unauthorised url

Tags: php

In my site I am allowing adding of images only after registration.
But if someone types url for the page for image addition without registration , what HTTP error should I show or ANY OTHER BETTER METHOD.

Comment: that has nothing to do with http. but if you have to use an http code, then try 401 unauthorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a custom page and display it using .htaccess file.